# how to deploy a php app with mysql to heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

I have a small php app that uses mySql for the database, I wish to deploy the app on heroku using the clearDB add on, But I am not sure how to do it, please help. 
I am presently using MAMP server locally which has MySQL installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are clueless about where to start, I suggest going through [Heroku PHP introduction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction). You'd basically need to adapt the `Provision a database` item, using your MySQL addon instead of the one used on the example.

Comment: what is you MySQL?

Comment: Oops typo. I meant your

Answer (score 0):

php and composer installed in your local machine . 
Then install Heroku Command Line Interface . once your done with this you can log in to heroku in ur local machine and you can create your heroku app and deploy should not be a problem .